# Unable to upgrade from Python2 to Python3 (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu-19.04

I had python2 installed in my ubuntu (19.04) and I wanted to get it upgraded to 3.7. I installed the 3.7 but still the version showed as 2.7. but I could run python3 and go to the console and python3.7 executable was available in /usr/bin. Did try all the tricks available in internet without any luck. then I decided to delete python2.7 executable from the /usr/bin and now I cannot even run pip as it tries to find the deleted 2.7 I guess. Getting the following message.

bash: /usr/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I don't know why it's still trying to find 2.7 like ex girl friend when 3.7 is installed and available in the machine.

Comment: 1) pip3 relies on python3 so you can run it; 2) removing python2 probably broke your system, as Ubuntu 19.04 **needs** python2.

Comment: Try to invoke it like python3 or python 3.7 maybe. You can use the python 3 pip like this: python3 -m pip

Comment: I didn't know that Python2 is needed. I will try re-install Python2 again

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a path for python 3.7 in your .bashrc file? If not, try that and that should help.

Usually a path is something like:

```
$ export PATH=$HOME/Nek5000/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

First, run an update to make sure that there aren’t newer versions of the required packages.

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

Next, you can try forcing Apt to look for and correct any missing dependencies or broken packages. This will actually install any missing packages and repair existing installs.

```
sudo apt install -f
```

([Source](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/))

Also, always remember - never install directly in global environment. You should always create a local environment first([i recommend venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)) as there are very high chances you can break something globally. 
You can create a local environment by -

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

where tutorial-env is the name of your environment.
To activate this environment, you should run

```
source tutorial-tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

Comment: I'm getting the following message when I try to execute sudo apt update --fix-missing                                                                           : Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1002 (packagekitd) - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/